# Order-agnostic regex - is it possible?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the following video url:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/F40ZBDAG8-o?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have the following:

```
^<iframe
(\swidth="\d{1,3}")?
(\sheight="\d{1,3}")?
(\salt=""[^""<>]*"")?
(\stitle=""[^""<>]*"")?
\ssrc="//(www.youtube.com|player.vimeo.com)/[-a-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+"
(\sframeborder="[^""<>]*")?
(\sallowfullscreen)?
\s?/?></iframe>$
```

This is working, but I can't rely on the fact that youtube will always provide embed links that follow this structure.  If they move the `width` attribute to after `src`, my regex will fail.

Is there any way to do order-agnostic groupings, to address this?

Comment: What are you trying to match ? Do you want to get only the src ? or do you want to extract as much of data possible out of the iframe ? Also, in a realworld example I would think that `^$` should be removed

Comment: @HamZa - trying to match an `iframe` that always has a `src` attribute that always starts with `vimeo` or `youtube`.  The other attributes - title, width, etc, are optional.  Closing tag required.

Comment: @RobVious So you don't even need the width, height, title etc ? which means you could simply use `<iframe[^>]+src\s*=("|')(.*?)\1\s*[^>]+>`. Now it's up to you to implement the "check" for finding youtube or vimeo videos :P

Comment: What the (now deleted) comments were saying is that an ordinary HTML Parser is almost always a better choice for parsing HTML than regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make each of the search terms a lookahead - these don't consume the strings, so they can be in any order. Example:

```
<iframe (?=.*height="\d{1,3}")(?=.*width="\d{1,3}").*
```

will match both

```
<iframe width="123" height="321"
```

and

```
<iframe height="321" width="123"
```

[demo on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/rG3wI7)

I am sure you can finish this yourself (adding all the terms you want to match).

Note - this "matches" - it does not "extract". But it will tell you that all these terms are present in the expression, in any order.

**EDIT** since I started writing this answer a number of comments appeared that change my understanding of your request. If you "just" want to extract the `src=` thing, you simply do

```
<iframe.*?src="([^"]+)"
```

and the match (the thing in brackets) will be whatever is between the first and the second double quote. Typically there are better tools than regex for parsing HTML - my personal preference is BeautifulSoup (Python).